# Lubuntu 15.0 on windows 8.1 win scp not connectiing

Tags: lubuntu, vmware

I have successfully installed Lubuntu 15.0 on Windows 8.1 but I'm not able to connect with Win SCP on VMware.

It always shows an error message as connection refused or connection timed out after 2 to 3 minutes.

Comment: Can you paste the error message on your question please.

Comment: So you are trying to connect using WinSCP on a Windows 8.1 host to Lubuntu on a VMWare virtual machine? How did you configure the VM's networking (bridged? NAT?). Did you install an SSH/SCP server on the Lubuntu system yet?

Answer (score 0):

simply add your network to home network just try to ping your VM Linux IP it should be if not then troubleshoot network by network wizard same applies for Linux to try to ping your windows host machine if both are ok then it will connect.
if not then troubleshoot and add the VM network to home /private network